# C Linked List: Does a remove_at_n function need realloc?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, realloc

I wrote a linked list in C and have a `node` and a `list` as `typedef`.  My implementation of push, remove, delete at n, and length work fine.  However, I was wondering if whenever I implement the `delete_n()` function, should I `realloc` the linked list?  Or does `realloc` only relevant for an array which I need to resize?  If so, it is a best practice or does it only matter if the list is extremely large?

```
typedef struct node{
    int item;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct list{
    Node *head;
}List;


void delete_n(List *l, int index){
    Node *left, *right;
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    if(l->head == NULL){
        printf("\n underflow \n");
        return;
    }
    else{
        right = l->head;
         while(i < index){
            left = right;
            right = right->next;
            ++i;
        }
        left->next = right->next;
        free(right);
    }
    return;
}
```

Implementation of a new node and pushing the node onto a list:

```
List *test_list;
test_list = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
```

When a node is created:

```
int new_local;
Node *node;
node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
printf("\nEnter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &new_local);
printf("\n");
node->item = new_local;
push(test_list, node);
```

Comment: 1) What does realloc do? 2) Do you need to do the thing realloc does?

Comment: I understand `realloc` is useful for resizing an array, but does `realloc` allocate the list to a new contiguous block?  If it does, would it be 'best practice' to `realloc` as the list is resized?

Comment: Did you allocate the entire list with a single call to `malloc`?

Comment: I allocated the list with multiple calls to `malloc`, each `node` is allocated memory, then pushed into the list.

Comment: `realloc` is for contiguous memory as you have pointed out. But each node in a linked list does not come from contiguous memory in the common implementation of linked list. If yours does then you need to explicitly state that and show the allocation part of the code.

Comment: @JJL Then you have answered your own question. None of the nodes/allocations need resizing. You are just getting rid of one node/allocation. The function to do that is of course `free` not `realloc`.

Comment: @kaylum - cool, thanks, I was curious about this and wanted to ask the community.